# How to link push send log to journey activity?

Tags: marketing-cloud, push

Is there a way to link push send log or the mobile push detailed report back to _journeyactivity?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID` field in `_JourneyActivity` is email-only.

It's more involved, but you can pull all Journey-related Subscriber-level activity data from this undocumented REST API endpoint.

When I say it's undocumented, I mean it's available publicly through the REST API discovery URLs, but the usage, properties, parameters, etc., have not been provided by Salesforce officially.

This data will contain information about all activities in your journey -- email, SMS, push, and custom journey builder activities:

```
POST /interaction/v1/interactions/journeyhistory/search?$pageSize=500&$page=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: {{tenant}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64

{
     "start": "2023-01-24T00:00:00.000Z"
    ,"end": null
}
```

Here's a blog post by [@Gortonington](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/12730/gortonington) on how you might get this data into a data extension to make it useful:  [Journey History for the Last 30 Days](https://gortonington.com/journey-history-for-last-30-days-via-api/)

Comment: Thanks @adam. Do you know whether we can join the result from this API to mobile push detailed report? cause this report tracks delivery and open activity which would be useful as we create a campaign tracking report. I'm aware datorama has this but we're trying to build it outside SFMC.

Comment: More likely the _SMSMessageTracking data view.